# Create an index on a CLOB column

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle11g

I have the table `interventi` which has this structure

```
describe interventi;
Name                           Null     Type
------------------------------ -------- -----------------------
DATAORA                        NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)
PARLAMENTARE                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(16)
TESTO                          NOT NULL CLOB()
```

where the filed dataora is the primary key. I filled this table with a sigle row

```
DATAORA                         PARLAMENTARE     TESTO
------------------------------- ---------------- ------------------------------- 
05-JUL-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM MRTMRZ           (CLOB) PIPPO PLUTO PAPERINO

1 rows selected
```

Now, I want create an index on the field testo

```
create index idx_testo_interventi
on interventi(testo) indextype is
ctxsys.context;
```

but

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
create index idx_testo_interventi
on interventi(testo) indextype is
ctxsys.context
Error at Command Line:1 Column:13
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10528: primary keys of type TIMESTAMP(6) are not allowed
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.
```

How can I create an index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little tweak might help.

Here's what doesn't work:

```
SQL> create table interventi
  2    (dataora      timestamp(6) primary key,
  3     parlamentare varchar2(16),
  4     testo        clob);

Table created.

SQL> create index idx_testo_interventi on interventi (testo)
  2    indextype is ctxsys.context;
create index idx_testo_interventi on interventi (testo)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10528: primary keys of type TIMESTAMP(6) are not allowed
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
```

And here's what you could do:

- include additional column (ID in my example) which will be used as a primary key
- populate it with a trigger, using a sequence
- column you used as a primary key until now set to be **unique not null** (which will act as if it was a primary key - no duplicates, no NULL values)

.

```
SQL> drop table interventi;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table interventi
  2    (id number    primary key,
  3     dataora      timestamp(6) unique not null,
  4     parlamentare varchar2(16),
  5     testo        clob);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seqa;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_inter
  2    before insert on interventi
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := seqa.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create index idx_testo_interventi on interventi (testo)
  2    indextype is ctxsys.context;

Index created.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: how to run CTX_DDL]**

You'll have to acquire privileges to run it. Here's how: connect as a privileged user (`SYS` being one of them, if you didn't create another) and `GRANT EXECUTE` on that package to user who is going to use it.

Have a look at the example: at first, it won't work (as you've already noticed):

```
SQL> exec ctx_ddl.sync_index('idx_testo_interventi');
BEGIN ctx_ddl.sync_index('idx_testo_interventi'); END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'CTX_DDL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Connect as `SYS` (or another privileged user, if you have it):

```
SQL> connect sys@xe as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant execute on ctx_ddl to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Back to the owner of the `interventi` table (and the index):

```
SQL> connect scott@xe
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> exec ctx_ddl.sync_index('idx_testo_interventi');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK.

Comment: The field dataora is the primary key and the primary key is unique and not null by default. I do not need either of another id (dataora is referenced from another table),  neither a trigger

Comment: Theoretically, as far as I can tell, you really don't need anything of that. However, if you plan to create an index on TESTO column & regarding `DRG-10528: primary keys of type TIMESTAMP(6) are not allowed` error message, how do you plan to keep the current data model and create an index?

Comment: I adopted tour solution and create the index. Now I must syncronized it. I used the following command
<code>execute ctx_ddl.sync_index('idx_testo_interventi');</code>
but oracle display which
<code>PLS-00201: identifier 'CTX_DDL' must be declared</code>

Comment: I edited my message by adding an example which shows how to run `ctx_ddl`; have a look, please.

Comment: @Littlefoot, there is no need in ID column. You can just convert dataora from PK to UK and that will do the trick. On the other hand, if data modeler prefers to have PK in each and every table you can add virtual column like "virtual_pk number generated always as (to_number(to_char(dataora,'yyyymmddhh24missff'))) primary key". So no need in trigger. 12c allows also identity columns as a PK.

Comment: Thank you for the information and the comment, @DrYWit. I don't know whether the OP really needs a PK or would the UK do. Though, as the question is tagged with Oracle 11 tag, I presume that the last part of the comment wouldn't work in this very case.

Comment: @DrYWit PK is primari key, ok, but what is UK?